# Google App Engine and Django-nonrel: db migration

Tags: google-app-engine, django-models, migration, django-nonrel, non-relational-database

I just started "Hello World" app on GAE and Django-nonrel. I saw a couple of differences between using pure Django on relational databases and Django-nonrel. The most sadly is South migration system inability in non-relational databases. **Is it exist some way to migrate models to database with GAE? If not, what strategy of models developing you would recommend in this case?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

South's main concern is handling issues regarding changes in relational db schemas.  This is not required in a non-rel db, where smart coding practices and simple scripts can handle migrations as an online operation.

See also:

- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html
- http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/

Keep in mind that many Django field types are [supported by djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#field-types).  This means you can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata) on your sql project to save your data  to files and later use [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) in your new project to load it into your models.

If you need further processing, you can create a small script that copies data from the old models to the new models.